# Applying different formula to each value in the list using if.. else

Tags: python, if-statement

I may miss very trivial thing. My purpose is to apply different conditions into each value in the list with if.. else command.

Code is like following:

```
import numpy as np

x1 = np.arange(20)
x1 = list(x1)
print x1
if x1>=3.5 or x1<=13.:
    x1 = np.array(x1)
    p1 = (885.4*x1**3)/1000

else:
    if  x1 < 3.5:
        p1 =0

    else:
        if x1 > 13.:
            p1 = 1500.
print x1
print p1
```

As you can see, I would like to get zero when x1 is less than 3.5 and 1500 when x1 is larger than 13 and  (885.4*x1**3)/1000 when x1 is smaller or equal to 13 and larger or equal to 3.5.

However I can not see value in the reulted list which command was applied when x1<3.5 and x1>13.

Result is:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
[0.00000000e+00   8.85400000e-01   7.08320000e+00   2.39058000e+01
   5.66656000e+01   1.10675000e+02   1.91246400e+02   3.03692200e+02
   4.53324800e+02   6.45456600e+02   8.85400000e+02   1.17846740e+03
   1.52997120e+03   1.94522380e+03   2.42953760e+03   2.98822500e+03
   3.62659840e+03   4.34997020e+03   5.16365280e+03   6.07295860e+03]
```

I will really appreciate any idea or help.

Best regards,

Hoonill

Comment: `x1>=3.5 or x1<=13.` is always `True`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to do this with numpy arrays, first define the conditions:

```
x = np.arange(20)
c1 = x < 3.5
c2 = (3.5<=x) & (x<=13.)
c3 = x > 13.
```

Then apply the different values to the parts of the array:

```
x[c1] = 0
x[c2] = 885.4*x[c2]**3)/1000
x[c3] = 1500
```

Comment: Thank you Jrsm, However I got the error of Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "practice2.py", line 10, in <module>
    x[c2] = 885.4*(x[c2])**3/1000
TypeError: array cannot be safely cast to required type
Do you have any idea of this? Thank you.

Comment: I guess that's because they were integers before and now you want them to be floats. Try creating the array as `x = np.arange(20, dtype=float)`.

Comment: I think by default np.arange(20) should create a double array. If you have integers you should use a cast i.e. x = x.astype("float"). You can determine the typ with "print x.dtype"

Comment: Thank you for Sukrit and jrsm. Both answers are really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You are applying the conditionals over the list and not its elements.

```
>>> x1 > 3.5
True
```

So, the first condition is applied and I believe `*` in `numpy.array` applies the formula to every element.

An easier way to apply what you are looking for would be to generate the array from scratch using the first array, so something like

```
In [19]: final = []

In [20]: for elem in x1:
    ...:     if elem >= 3.5 and elem <= 13.:
    ...:         final.append((885.4*elem**3)/1000)
    ...:     else:
    ...:         if elem < 3.5:
    ...:             final.append(0)
    ...:         else:
    ...:             final.append(1500)
    ...:             

In [21]: final
Out[21]: 
[0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 56.665599999999998,
 110.675,
 191.24639999999999,
 303.69220000000001,
 453.32479999999998,
 645.45659999999998,
 885.39999999999998,
 1178.4674,
 1529.9712,
 1945.2238,
 1500,
 1500,
 1500,
 1500,
 1500,
 1500]
```

Of course you need to change your conditions, since every number in the list is either greater than 3.5 or less than 13.

**Although, a better numpy way to do it would be as specified in @jrsm's answer!**

Comment: Thnak you Sukrit, I am still bit confused. How should I do if I would like to apply second and third condition over the list as well?

Comment: @Isaac: Glad we helped you out. Don't forget to mark the answer which helped you out as accepted. :)